# Huge garbage created at regular intervals in Wildfly 8.2.0.Final

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection, wildfly, wildfly-8, undertow

Huge garbage is created in wildfly every couple of minutes. Though Full GC is able to reclaim memory, this causes frequent full gcs, as heap is getting occupied due to the increase in number of objects created . We can reproduce this issue in 60 users Jmeter loadtest. This was not the case in Jboss 7.1.1Final.

After analyzing heapdumps,   Huge char arrays are created and they are not garbage collected by Minor GC.  Incoming reference for the char array suggest that they have valid reference to io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl. However full gc is able to recover the memory. Not sure why attributes in  io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl are not getting gced by minor gc's.

"org.apache.struts.tiles.ComponentContext"  is kept in  attributes Map by io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.  org.apache.struts.tiles.ComponentContext contains a big char array.
We suspect issue with undertow.
 Images obtained from Eclipse MAT attached  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qgsitzb7x27j8kc/AABoQwR1qPwTPiDtO6B0_Pm7a?dl=0

Comment: Considering that strus doesn't ship with wildfly, how did you conclude that?

Comment: We use struts and tiles in the application.Char references showed that  org.apache.struts.tiles.ComponentContext is holding reference as an attribute inside io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl which is not getting gced immediately.